# First player to win k matches of series of n, win probability p = 0.5

Tags: probability, random-walk

A series of matches are held between *n* identical competitors. Each is won by one of the *n* with equal probability (no ties). I'm looking for a probabilistic description of the outcome when looking at the first player to win 1, 2, ... matches.

For example, if player #3 is the first player to win 400 matches, she has a better than 1/n chance to be the first player to win 401 matches.

In particular: how many matches need to be played before some player wins *k*? (The dominant term is of course *kn* but what is the next (negative) term?) How often does the lead change places? (I expect infinitely often, but with decreasing frequency... maybe sqrt-ly many times?)

I have a decent math background but have not studied any probability since a basic undergrad class.

Related question: [How long until everyone is in the lead?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195285/1778)

Comment: Title is somewhat misleading when reading your text. Do you want to win $n$ matches as in there are $n$ competitors or are you interested in winning $k$ matches for some $k$ independant of $n$, the number of players?

Comment: There seem to be three quite different questions (or more) here. 1) Probability that player A is the first to win $k+1$ games, given that he was the first to win $k$ games. 2) how many matches (expectation? full distribution) need to be played before some player wins $k$. 3) distribution of the event "the leader changed" (what about ties?)

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: I edited the title.

Comment: This is the special-case where win probability $p=0.5$, hence $q=1-p=0.5$, so you get nice clean $p^k q^{n-k} = 1/2^n$ in every term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not simple.

For $n=2$ you can base this on the probability or number of ways of reaching the previous step of having one of the players having one have won $k-1$ games and nobody else having won more, giving the expression $$2 \sum_{j=k}^{2k-1} \left. j {j-1 \choose k-1} \middle/ 2^j \right.$$ $$= 2k \left(1 - {2k \choose k} \middle/ 4^k \right).$$

For $n \gt 2$ you can develop a similar approach based on

$$n \sum_{j=k}^{nk-n+1} \left. j {j-1 \choose k-1} f(j-k,n-1,k-1) \middle/ n^j \right.$$

where $f(a,b,c)$ is the number of ways of putting $a$ labelled balls into $b$ labelled boxes subject to each box having no more than $c$ balls.

***Added***

You might want to look at: Klamkin, M. S. and Newman, D. J. "Extensions of the Birthday Surprise." J. Combin. Th. 3, 279-282, 1967.

I have not read it, but apparently it gives expressions like $$\int_0^\infty \left(e_{k-1}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n \, e^{-t} \, dt$$ where $e_{k-1}(x) = 1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\cdots + \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$ is a truncated exponential, and asymptotic values like $$\left(k!\right)^{1/k} \,\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \, n^{1-1/k} $$ for fixed $k$ as $n$ increases.  For $n=365$ and and $k=2$, the first of these gives about $24.616585894$, which is correct (we are looking for the mean not the median of the birthday problem)  and the second gives about $23.9$.

Comment: Any chance of an asymptotic? I am interested in cases where n is large (millions).